# Vuejs register component and getting did you register the component correctly? error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In one of our project i try to use [vuejs-countdown-timer](https://github.com/TriDiamond/vuejs-countdown-timer) component, but i get this error

> Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component
> correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name"
> option.

in this package documentation we have:

> //Installation
>
> npm i vuejs-countdown-timer -S Import component
>
> // global register at main.js import VueCountdownTimer from
> 'vuejs-countdown-timer';
>
> Vue.use(VueCountdownTimer);

and basic usage of that:

```js
<template>
    <vue-countdown-timer
      @start_callback="startCallBack('event started')"
      @end_callback="endCallBack('event ended')"
      :start-time="'2018-10-10 00:00:00'"
      :end-time="1481450115"
      :interval="1000"
      :start-label="'Until start:'"
      :end-label="'Until end:'"
      label-position="begin"
      :end-text="'Event ended!'"
      :day-txt="'days'"
      :hour-txt="'hours'"
      :minutes-txt="'minutes'"
      :seconds-txt="'seconds'">
    </vue-countdown-timer>
</template>

<script >
export default {
  name: 'Timer',
  methods: {
    startCallBack: function(x) {
      console.log(x);
    },
    endCallBack: function(x) {
      console.log(x);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

now after installing the package i imported into my `app.js`:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

import VueCountdownTimer from 'vuejs-countdown-timer';


Vue.use(Vuelidate)
Vue.use(VueCountdownTimer)
window.Vue = require('vue').default

import Timer from './components/partials/timer.vue'


new Vue({
    store,
    components: {
        Timer,
        //
    }, computed: {}, mount: {}
}).$mount('#app')
```

and after that i try to use into `html` template as:

```html
<login inline-template>
    <div class="page-content">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            ...
        </div>

        <Timer></Timer>

    </div>
</login>
```

my `login.js` content:

```js
import {required, minLength, maxLength} from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'
import axios from "axios";
import {route} from "../../routes";

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think inside login.js you should also import the component and register it

Comment: @Sibellekhayrallah is right, You need to import the `Timer` in the login.js as well.

Comment: Apparently, there is a problem with the `vuejs-countdown-timer` package. I've tried using it in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-meninsky-jf73z?file=/src/main.js) and it fails the very `import`. I opened [an issue](https://github.com/TriDiamond/vuejs-countdown-timer/issues/16) on its repo.

Comment: The maintainer of the package refused to acknowledge the problem, and also seems to have lied for no apparent reason, which is bewildering, to say the least. I'd stay clear of their code.

Answer (score -1):

Register vue-countdown-timer globally in app.js and your custom component timer locally in login.js

app.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import VueCountdownTimer from 'vuejs-countdown-timer';


Vue.use(Vuelidate)
Vue.use(VueCountdownTimer)
window.Vue = require('vue').default

new Vue({
    store,
    computed: {}, mount: {}
}).$mount('#app')
```

Login.js

```
import {required, minLength, maxLength} from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'
import axios from "axios";
import {route} from "../../routes";
import Timer from '../partials/timer.vue'


export default {
    data() {
        return {
            //
        }
    },
    components: {
      Timer
    },
}
```

Comment: Apparently, there is a problem with the `vuejs-countdown-timer` package at the moment. Could you provide a [mcve] where what you are suggesting actually works?

Comment: The issue seems to be with your custom component Timer. I've registered it correctly.

Comment: Sweet. Please provide a link to a codesandbox where it works. It doesn't have to be codesandbox. Use any other similar service. Thank you.

Comment: You are right. The issue is reported on their github repo.